# Передать # в URL в параметре запроса в ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, rest, spring-boot

Есть у меня такой url:

```
bookManag/book?name=world and war #2&field=1
```

передаю в параметре name - world and war #2 проблема в том, что после # всё обрезается и следующий параметр field не приходит. Хорошо, я нашёл как выйти из этой ситуации и заменил решётку на %23

```
bookManag/book?name=world and war %232&field=1
```

Но основная проблема не в этом, пытаюсь получить ответ через ResponseEntity

```
    String url = "http://localhost:8081/bookManag/book?name=world and war %232&field=1";
    org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, getRespType(), params);
```

После и происходит ошибка уже внутри спринга, вместо моего правильного url, spring его переделывает в

```
"http://localhost:8081/bookManag/book?name=world and war %20%25232&field=1"
```

заменяя %23 на %2523, что в итоге дает не правильный результат. Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: urlencoding используете чтобы заменить спецсимволы

Comment: @SeniorPomidor https://www.design-sites.ru/utility/url-encoding.php пробовал вот тут, решетка не кодируется

Comment: Попробуйте использовать вместо ``String url`` ``url = "http://localhost:8081/bookManag/book?name=world and war %232&field=1";`` - В Java я ваще не шарю, если че.

Comment: @1stSentinel31YearPerlHist не понял на что заменить?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor там проблема именно в том, что %23 кодируется в %2523.

Comment: @Kotysh, щас 5 сек

Comment: ``new URL("http", "localhost:8081", "/bookManag/book?name=world and war %232&field=1");`` - Вот так попробуйте написать.

Comment: @1stSentinel31YearPerlHist нет, так не получится, там надо строку передовать, а если вызывать после new URL().toString(), то получится тоже самое

Comment: ммм, ну ладно, подождём специалиста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для кодирования URL надо использовать [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/net/URLEncoder.html), в частности его метод encode
Вам достаточно прогнать через encode только часть URL-а c решеткой

```
String url = "http://localhost:8081/bookManag/book?name=" + URLEncoder.encode("world and war #2", "UTF-8") + "&field=1";
```

В результате у Вас получится строка вида `http://localhost:8081/bookManag/book?name=world+and+war+%232&field=1`, которая вполне себе валидный URL